# C# как обратиться к элементу на второй форме

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста. На форме1 делаю кнопку `button1`, добавляю через проект вторую форму, на ней в конструкторе ставлю `checkbox1`. 
Как в методе button1 обратиться к элементу `checkbox1`? 
например

```
if(checkbox1.checked)
{
}
```

Comment: Для этого у второй формы должна быть, понятно, ссылка на первую форму.

Comment: @VladD, можете объяснить, пожалуйста, на примере?

Comment: А что именно? Если есть ссылка `f1`, то вы обращаетесь к чекбоксу как `f1.checkbox1`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Выставляете у `checkBox` значение свойства `Modifers` равное `Public` или `Internal` (если обе формы из одного пространства имён и обращения к элементам управления второй формы из других пространств имён не предполагается).
2. Создаёте экземпляр второй формы. Например так:

   `Form2 f2 = new Form2();`
3. После этого обращаетесь к `checkBox` следующим образом: `f2.checkBox`.

Ничего сложного здесь особо нет.